# How to define arrays in zsh with user supplied key names

Tags: shell-script, zsh, array

I just started using zsh and I can't figure out how to define arrays with user defined keys.

(I'm following the documentations on arrays: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Array-Parameters)

```
➜ ~ array=(one [3]=three four)
zsh: no matches found: [3]=three four
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Is there a way we can define an array with user defined index names like in bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax was introduced in [54b395844030342213cacba4c569a6c5e6781c46](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/commit/54b395844030342213cacba4c569a6c5e6781c46) which was first [released](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/releases.html) in zsh 5.5 in April 2018. Your zsh version is presumably older than that.

In older versions, you can use separate assignments for each key.

```
array=(one)
array[3]=three
array[4]=four
```

Note that if you want an associative array (with strings as keys, not positive integers), you must first declare the array with `typeset -A array`.